# Does WEBUTIL.PLL (along with JARSIGNER) need to be compiled for each database used on the Oracle WebLogic: Oracle Forms and Reports server?

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, oracleforms

Does WEBUTIL.PLL need to be compiled for each database on the Oracle WebLogic: Oracle Forms and Reports 12.2.1.4 server? Most of the applications reside on database: X, however this particular application: application7 resides on database: Y.

Does WEBUTIL.PLL (along with JARSIGNER) need to be compiled for each database used on the Oracle WebLogic: Oracle Forms and Reports 12.2.1.4 server?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you are asking.  The webutil.pll file must be generated into webutil.plx in order to be usable at runtime.  That PLX file must be generated on the machine where the middletier software is installed and will be run.

Regarding "jarsigner", this is a Java utility with the JDK and not something you need to nor should you alter.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for responding.  As long as the PLX is generated on the machine, I am able to utilize the PLX for any application...on any database, on the machine?

Comment: In most cases, it can be any DB as long as the objects in any other DB are exactly the same as what was used to create the X file in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Michael!  I really appreciate the information.